# Error while connecting to MySQL on local docker container: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115)

Tags: mysql, docker

I try to connect to MySQL database which is run as a docker service (created from mysql:5.7 image) on my local docker. When I try:

```
mysql -u myuser -p mydb -h 127.0.0.1
```

I get the following error: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115)`
My docker settings for MySQL service is as the following:

```
networks:
  front-tier:
    name: front-tier
    attachable: true
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 70.28.0.0/16
  back-tier:
    name: back-tier
    attachable: true

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    hostname: mysql
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    placement:
    replicas: 1
  labels:
    com.dgyar.description: "Data node"
    com.dgyar.department: "IT"
  command: --sql_mode=""
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ******
    MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
    MYSQL_USER: myuser
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: ******
    MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
  networks:
    - back-tier
  volumes:
    - "/mnt/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map a port from your MySQL container onto your host in order to access it from your command.

For example

```
networks:
  front-tier:
    name: front-tier
    attachable: true
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 70.28.0.0/16
  back-tier:
    name: back-tier
    attachable: true

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    hostname: mysql
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    placement:
    replicas: 1
  labels:
    com.dgyar.description: "Data node"
    com.dgyar.department: "IT"
  command: --sql_mode=""
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ******
    MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
    MYSQL_USER: myuser
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: ******
    MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
  networks:
    - back-tier
  volumes:
    - "/mnt/mysql:/var/lib/mysql"
  ports:
    - "5000:3306"
```

```sh
mysql -u myuser -p mydb -h 127.0.0.1 -P 5000
```

Comment: Yes!. Thanks. I had forgotten it, simply :)